# How to find closest array of numbers to a target array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the code below. Is there a way to get the closet array which are matching in all items with the goal array?

```js
var counts = [
              [4,9,15],
              [2,11,81],
              [20,12,80],
              [14,3,80],
              [15,6,2],
              ]
  goal = [14,10,70];

var closest = counts.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
  return (Math.abs(curr - goal) < Math.abs(prev - goal) ? curr : prev);
});

console.log(closest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: please add the goal and the wanted result.

Comment: Well, not sure how to say this but visually speaking the `20,12,80` set is more closer than other options so how I can gab that through code?

Comment: You must write what result you want. And you DON`T need jQuery for that.

Comment: Does the position of the values has a meaning? is `[20,12,80]` and `[80,20,12]` considered to be the same? Or is it to compare the first value in the goal with the first value from counts?

Comment: Hi Mona. I am a volunteer editor here, and from time to time I edit and improve questions so they are as readable and succinct as possible for future readers. I notice that your questions feature quite a lot of [fluff material](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260776), some of which carries a helpless, pleading tone. Would you be able to make these a bit more succinct? [This discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366264) may be a useful resource - it's about the effect of begging towards volunteer helpers.

Comment: There is [strong preference for sentence case titles](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252624/title-case-or-sentence-case) on Stack Overflow. As a point of interest, title case headings are out of fashion amongst writers and typographers, and are generally only used for formal purposes these days. I have edited a number of your titles already, so it would save me some work if you would switch.

Answer (score 2):

You can look at it with distances in an n-dimensional space (3 in this case)

```js
var counts = [
              [4,9,15],
              [2,11,81],
              [20,12,80],
              [14,3,80],
              [15,6,2],
              ]
  goal = [14,10,70];

var best = Infinity;
var closest = null;
for(var i in counts) {
  var sum = 0;
  for(var j in counts[i]) {
    sum += (goal[j] - counts[i][j])**2;
  }
  if ((sum**.5) < best) {
    closest = counts[i];
    best = sum**.5;
  }
}

console.log(closest);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a delta function which takes two arrays and return the sum of the absolute difference,

```js
const delta = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v, i) => r + Math.abs(v - b[i]), 0);

var counts = [[4, 9, 15], [2, 11, 81], [20, 12, 80], [14, 3, 80], [15, 6, 2]],
    goal = [14, 10, 70],
    closest = counts.reduce((a, b) => delta(a, goal) < delta(b, goal) ? a : b);

console.log(closest);
```

by using the square of the delta

```js
const delta = (a, b) => a.reduce((r, v, i) => r + (v - b[i]) ** 2, 0);

var counts = [[4, 9, 15], [2, 11, 81], [20, 12, 80], [14, 3, 80], [15, 6, 2]],
    goal = [14, 10, 70],
    closest = counts.reduce((a, b) => delta(a, goal) < delta(b, goal) ? a : b);

console.log(closest);
```

Comment: No need abs if you square :)